# Uploading file to Facebook from Salesforce

Tags: apex, api, url, code, facebook

I'm trying to upload an image file to Facebook from Salesforce and current this is my codes and it is not working can anyone help me fix it?

***Please Note that my Image file is inside the Accounts Notes & Attachments***

---

I tested the string that I use for salesforcephoto and it Uploaded something onto Facebook using the Facebook Graph API explorer
[image: Uploaded using Facebook Graph API Explorer]

Save Session for the Facebook Graph API Explorer **[Click Here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?session_id=396918057359399)**

---

**The String I use for salesforcephoto**

```
String salesforcephoto = 'https://c.ap4.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?file='+lstRelatedAttach[0].Id+'&oid=' + orgid ;
```

**The Codes are**
[image: Codes]

---

**Debug Log Errors**

[image: Debug Log Errors]

---

**Redirecting to login page**

Currently this my link I'm using for my testing and it will redirect me to the login page instead of showing the image.

https://c.ap4.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=00P6F00001G81jz&oid=00D6F000001vFKh

---

I have tested this other link but it will give me an error message

https://c.ap4.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=00P6F00001G81jz&oid=00D6F000001vFKh

[image]

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to upload a photo onto Facebook from Salesforce
using the photo's URL that is from Salesforce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to add the file to the a document folder before I can access the url at other locations

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that stands out to me is that you have that url for the salesforce document added directly as a query string parameter, when you should url encode it first:

```
...'/Photos?url=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(salesforcephoto, 'UTF-8');
```

Also the format of the salesforce document url should be something like:

```
https://c.ap4.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=<id>&oid=<oid>&lastMod=1490673363000
```

Where `<id>` is the id of the document, and `<oid>` is the id of you org. I believe the `lastMod` param is optional.

That other url with the resource at `/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=` is for the same image, but requires login.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56369/discussion-on-answer-by-martin-adding-salesforce-sso-apex-code).